# Changing country in Android play store is not working, how can I change it?

Tags: google-play-store, localization

I have moved from Hong Kong to the UK. I am now physically in the UK connected to the UK network with a UK number and a UK SIM. However, I can't change my Play Store country to the UK.

Initially, in the Play Store app in Android, under country and profiles, there was Hong Kong and it suggested me to change to the UK, listing a few options how I can add a payment method, including adding credit / debit card, Three Pay, etc.

I tapped adding credit / debit card, and it showed a warning saying that I won't be able to use my current balance, and I won't be able to change again for 365 days. I tapped continue, the warning disappeared, and nothing happened.

I then used my computer to signed in Google Pay, created a UK profile, and added a UK debit card to it. Then under country and profiles, both Hong Kong and the UK appeared, with Hong Kong selected.

[image: first step]

When I tapped the UK, the same warning appeared, and after I tapped continue, the warning disappeared and nothing happened.

[image: second step]

I have two Android phones and they behave the same. I cannot delete my Hong Kong payment profile as I have a Developer account and an AdSense account tied to it. How can I change my Play Store country to the UK?

I have tried deleting storage and cache for my Play Store, and also tried removing the Google account and adding back in, but they didn't help. Initially on the first day I landed the UK a box did appear for me to enter my account details, but I hadn't got my debit card yet at that moment so I didn't continue.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469010/migrate-google-merchant-account-to-different-country?

Answer (score 0):

I used a 3rd phone with an older Android version, added my Google account into that phone, and changed using the exact same way in the Play Store.